# USB-MIDI controller freezes when used with live-drawing software "Tagtool"

Tags: midi

I do live drawing performances with the "Tagtool" software (the old school version: http://www.tagtool.org/wp/). It is a piece of software that allows you to draw using a drawing tablet and an arduino-based controller and animate these drawings live with a game controller (and project them as a performance).

Instead of using an arduino-based controller I wanted to use a KORG NanoKontrol2 MIDI-controller. I had seen a video of someone using the older version Nanokontrol which seemed to work fine and the Tagtool software can easily be altered to run with MIDI.

I managed to hook up everything ok and could control the values of color, transparency, line-thickness, etc… with the sliders of the MIDI-controller like I expected. However, this only works when I move the sliders gently! When I move them too fast, the whole thing just freezes and none of the values can be moved. I have to restart the Tagtool program in order for it to work again.

I already posted this question to a forum dedicated to the Tagtool itself, but nobody seemed to have any idea what this could be, nor had they encountered this problem before (so it's not a known issue when using MIDI to control the Tagtool).

I have managed to find a workaround which solves my problem, but it is just a workaround and I still have no idea what is going on exactly...

In testing whether it was the Nanokontrol which was the problem or the software, I hooked it up to some other software which all seemed to work fine. No freezing. At one point I used the MIDI-tester software MIDI-OX to see the values of the sliders and knobs. This worked fine too, no freezes. So I concluded the controller itself was ok.

But when I then started the Tagtool program again, this also worked perfectly! No more freezing whatsoever...

I shut everything down and started everything up again, and the freezing was back! What had happened? The first time I had left that MIDI-OX program running and the second time I didn't. So for some reason, as long as I keep MIDI-OX running in the background, I can fiddle those MIDI-knobs as fast as I can, no problem.

Of course, this is just a workaround. I would be very interested to know what is actually happening here, and why the Tagtool freezes without the MIDI-OX.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be about a problem with your specific configuration.